# Loading external Div using iFrame Alternative

Tags: javascript

I'm currently designing a eBay listing template for a client in which i have managed to load JavaScript using a loader (www.test4.solowebs.co.uk). The JavaScript works in eBay without giving me an error which is fantastic as i used a loader rather than script. What i want is - at the bottom of the listing i want an external div to load from another site, (my own site test4.solowebs.co.uk/featured.html) which has in it two offers. The result of this is that i can change the offers on that page and it will automatically load into all of my listings, a bit like a iFrame. (only problem is eBay does not allow iFrames - and i haven't been able to find a workaround.)

The Question - Is there a way i can load an iFrame using Javascript? Or an alternate method which will allow me to load a div from an external page? (as ebay hosts the HTML it will have to be cross-domain compatible!) I'm an expert in HTML CSS and OK at JavaScript so anything other than that will have to be detailed and instructions to implement given.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX, or technically speaking: XMLHttpRequest.

Here's an article on SO about an in-line cross-browser XMLHttpRequest script: [Cross-Browser XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557247/easiest-way-to-retrieve-cross-browser-xmlhttprequest)

Use it to populate your div asynchronously. Hope this helps.