# Pass a data from javascript to PHP without click anything

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to pass data from javascript to PHP without loading a page or without click anything. When I open the page, It will automatically append the `a` and `b` to url. Thanks in advance

Here's my javascript code:

```
<script>
    var a = "bully";
    var b = "burger";
    window.location.href = "somepage.php?a=" + hello + "&b=" + world;
</script>
```

Here's PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['a']) && isset($_GET['b'])){
         echo $_GET['a'] . $_GET['b'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP is processed before the page is even sent to the client so the only way to pass information from Javascript to PHP without reloading is through an AJAX call.

Comment: Can you help me with ajax. I'm new to javascript. Thank you

Comment: See Leandro's answer. jQuery makes this process simple, especially for beginners.

Comment: Thank you. but is there any way to do this with plain javascript and ajax?

Comment: Of course, since jQuery is only a javascript library.
TutsPlus has a good screencast for this.
http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript--net-4855

Comment: There is also this good reference over here (besides the one I've mentioned in the other answer's reply): http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28325/implementing-a-cross-browser-ajax-utility-as-an-exercise

Answer (score 0):

You can just make an AJAX call. For a shortcut to get there I recommend you to use jQuery for this job. [Get it here](http://jquery.com/download/). Then you just need to do something like this:

```
var a = "bully";
var b = "burger";
$.get("somepage.php?a=" + a + "&b=" + b);
```

To see how this "get" function works, click here for the [API documentation reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: Thank you. If possible I don't want to use jquery libray.

Comment: In this case check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2557268/1170086 -- which is a snippet reference to pure JS use of "AJAX", commonly called XMLHttpRequest (a.k.a XHR).

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on Google Chrome browser.

**script.js**

AJAX request uses XMLHttpRequest object. It is well explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

```
var a = "bully";
var b = "burger";

var url = 'process.php?a=' +a+ '&b=' +b;

console.log('sending request ...');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    // create the object

// ajax on load
xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    console.log('Response loaded: ' +this.responseText);
    document.body.innerHTML = this.responseText;


    // change the url on the address bar
    // pushState(object or string, title, newUrl)
    window.history.pushState({a: a, b: b}, 'Title: ' +a+ ' ' +b, '?a=' +a+ '&b=' +b);
}, false);

// ajax on error
xhr.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Failed to load the response.');
    document.body.innerHTML = 'Failed to load the response.';
}, false);

// open(method, url, isAsynchronous). Should be called after we set all events.
xhr.open('GET', url, true);    // open the connection.
xhr.send();    // send the request.
```

**index.html**

Just include the javascript file to do AJAX request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

This script gets the parameters sent by the javascript.

```
<?php

$a = $_GET['a'];
$b = $_GET['b'];
echo $a. ' ' .$b;
```

**P.S. Edited**

Add window.history.pushState() in "load" event to update/change the current url on address bar. See [here](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page)

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible if I enter this in url `process.php`, It will automatically append `?a=' +a+ '&b=' +b` ?

Comment: Did you mean to append the parameters (a and b) to the current page url (index.html to become index.html?a=bully&b=burger)?

Comment: That's what I need to happen.

Comment: Code updated to use pushState() function. But this will work with modern browsers. :)