# Having issue showing the ajax result in a textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to do is show my ajax result in my count inputbox.

I tried to use `alert()` to know if my AJAX return a value and it gives value.

My problem is it doesnt show in my count inputbox the result in my AJAX.

**script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var countTimer = setInterval(
        function ()
        {
            codeValue();        
        }, 500);

function codeValue(){

        var data = {};
        data.countValue = $('#countValue').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "codeTime.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            $("#count").val(result.user_code);

            }
        });

};

});
```

**response:**

```
{"user_code":2}
```

Comment: put console.log(result) in success method and see the response from the server.

Comment: Is the alert data a json object with the result.user_code entry?

Comment: Can you paste the response as well?

Comment: @Devendra Soni it still gives the result i wanted

Comment: @tobiasandersen here is the response {"user_code":2}

Comment: use $("#count").val( JSON.stringify(result.user_code));
you are trying to put an object in the val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php code return a json string, not a javascript object. You can specify the `dataType` or parse it yourself in the callback function.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "codeTime.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
        $("#count").val(result.user_code);
    }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "codeTime.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        result = JSON.parse(result);       // parse the json string into a javascript object
        $("#count").val(result.user_code);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `dataType: 'json'` in the `ajax`

Like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "codeTime.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
        $("#count").val(result.user_code);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the **jQuery** library to achieve this:

### **First step - Call a function when the body onload event is triggered:**

You need to trigger a **JavaScript** function when the document is loaded, using the `onload` property in your *HTML* `body` tag, like this:

```
<body onload="ini()">

(...)

</body>
```

### **Second step - Make an AJAX call to your PHP file:**

You need to call your server side script using *AJAX*. Your **JavaScript** code will look like this:

```
function ini()
{
    var interVal = setInterval(function() { ajaxCall() }, 500);
    // you can later on:
    // clearInterval(interVal);
    // if you need to
}

function ajaxCall()
{
    // Store the "countValue"
    var countValue = document.getElementById('countValue').value;

    // Store your POST variables, to be sent to the SERVER side
    postData = "countValue=" + encodeURIComponent(countValue);
    // you can send multiple post variables using the & separator
    // like this:
    // var1=encodeURIComponent(value1)&var2=encodeURIComponent(value2)

    // Create an XML HTTP Request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Set the content Type of your request
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

    // Set the lambda function to execute when the ready state changes 
    // You need to set this function in the onreadystatechange property
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    { // Ready state changed
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) { // Response arrived Succesfully

            // Parse and Store the responseText of the XML HTTP Request
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            document.getElementById('count').value = jsonObj['user_code'];
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST', 'codeTime.php', true);
    xhr.send(postData);
}
```

### **Advice:**

Only use a library when you need to, even if it's `jQuery` =)

Comment: Only use a library when you want to make sure your app works in all browsers.

Comment: @true, XMLHttpRequest will work for IE7+, if you need IE6 support, you can use something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557247/easiest-way-to-retrieve-cross-browser-xmlhttprequest
I don't see a real need for jQuery for doing AJAX, anyway, that's just my opinion / preference. If you want to use jQuery for AJAX, I'm fine with it. :P