# Memory Leak with socket.io + node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I appear to have a memory leak with my Node.js application. I built it quickly, and my JavaScript isn't too strong, so this might be easy.

I've done some heap dumps on it, and it's the String `object`? leaking memory, at the rate of about 1MB every 5 minutes. I expanded String, and it's actually String.Array?

Heap stack:
[image]

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node

var port = 8081;

var io = require('socket.io').listen(port),
sys = require('sys'),
daemon = require('daemon'),
mysql = require('mysql-libmysqlclient');

var updateq = "SELECT 1=1";
var countq = "SELECT 2=2";

io.set('log level', 2);


process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});

var connections = 0;

var conn = mysql.createConnectionSync();
dbconnect();

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){ 
  connections++;
  client.on('disconnect', function(){ connections--;  }) 
});

process.on('exit', function () {
    console.log('Exiting');
    dbdisconnect();
});

function dbdisconnect() {
     conn.closeSync();
}

function dbconnect() {
    conn.connectSync('leet.hacker.org','user','password');
}


function update() {
    if (connections == 0)
        return;
    conn.query(updateq, function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        dbdisconnect();
        dbconnect();
        return;
      }
      res.fetchAll(function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
        io.sockets.json.send(rows);
      });
    });
}

function totals() {
    if (connections == 0)
        return;
        conn.query(countq, function (err, res) {
          if (err) {
        // Chances are that the server has just disconnected, lets try reconnecting
        dbdisconnect();
        dbconnect();
            throw err;
          }
          res.fetchAll(function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            }
        io.sockets.json.send(rows);
          });
        });

}

setInterval(update, 250);
setInterval(totals,1000);

setInterval(function() {
console.log("Number of connections: " + connections);
},1800000);



  daemon.daemonize('/var/log/epiclog.log', '/var/run/mything.pid', function (err, pid) {
    // We are now in the daemon process
    if (err) return sys.puts('Error starting daemon: ' + err);

    sys.puts('Daemon started successfully with pid: ' + pid);
  });
```

**Current version**

```
function totals() {

        if (connections > 0)
        {
                var q = "SELECT query FROM table";

            db.query(q, function (err, results, fields) {
            if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return false;
            }

            for (var row in results)
            {
                    io.sockets.send("{ ID: '" + results[row].ID + "', event: '" + results[row].event + "', free: '" + results[row].free + "', total: '" + results[row].total + "', state: '" + results[row]$
                    row = null;
            }


            results = null;
            fields = null;
            err = null;
            q = null;
            });
    }
}
```

Still leaking memory, but it seems only on these conditions:

- From startup, with no clients -> Fine
- 1st client connection -> Fine
- 2nd client (even with the 1st client disconnecting and reconnecting) -> Leaking memory
- Stop all connections -> Fine
- 1 new connection (connections = 1) -> Leaking memory

Comment: Informative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733665/how-to-prevent-memory-leaks-in-node-js

Comment: `connectSync` :(

Comment: You mention you modified String to contain String.Array, and even point us to that in your memory snapshot, but I see nothing in your code that would use this, nor what you actually did to create String.Array

Comment: @Raynos: I know, I need to find a better MySQL client.

Comment: @Matt, I'm not using String.Array. That's just what I noticed was increasing in memory from the heap snapshots.

Comment: When you say it increases at a rate of 1MB / 5 minutes, how many connections is that? If you increase the # of connections, does the leak grow faster? How about in proportion to the # of messages sent from the client?

Comment: @Matt - I was running it in debug mode, so only one connection (me).

Comment: @Matt - Client doesn't send any messages back to the server. As for Server -> Client: update() generates around 10-20 messages per 'tick'. totals() is around 25 messages per second.

Comment: I've compared heapstacks at the start and end of both of my functions, and they are not increasing in memory. So it must be from a component I'm using.

Comment: **Updates**: I replaced the mysql-libmysqlclient with just mysql (npm package), and no changes there. I have noticed when it increases though:

When the first user connects, memory usage is fine, and it's great
When this user reconnects, or another user connects, we start leaking
All users disconnect, it's fine
1 new person connects, and we're leaking again

So I'm thinking it's something to do with socket.io. I'm using the new version, that was released last week.

Comment: I would suspect JSON serialization to be at least related to the leak - did you running it without `io.sockets.json.send`?

Comment: @Wladimir Palant - Tried that (just sending the json as a string), and it still leaks memory. I've edited the OP with the current copy of one of the functions.

Comment: @giggsey sounds like a socket.io leak. Go file a bug

Comment: For all: I've filed a bug report with the Socket.IO guys, and they are looking into it: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/299

Answer (score 5):

Do yourself a favour and use [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), it's a pure javascript mysql client and it's fast. Other than that, you should be using asynchronous code to stop IO being blocked whilst you're working. Using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library will help you here. It has code for waterfall callback passing among other things.

As for your memory leaking, it probably isn't socket.io, although I haven't used it in a few months, I have had many thousands of concurrent connections and not leaked memory, and my code wasn't the best either.

Two things, however. Firstly your code is faily unreadable. I suggest looking into properly formatting your code (I use two spaces for every indentation but some people use four). Secondly, printing the number of connections every half an hour seems a little silly, when you could do something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
  process.stdout.write('Current connections: ' + connections + '     \r');
}, 1000);
```

The `\r` will cause the line to be read back to the start of the line and overwrite the characters there, which will replace the line and not create a huge amount of scrollback. This will help with debugging if you choose to put debugging details in your logging.

You can also use `process.memoryUsage()` for quickly checking the memory usage (or how much node thinks you're using).

Comment: Thanks. Although it is currently believed to be a memory leak in socket.io - See: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/299

Answer (score 0):

Could this be related to the connected clients array not clearing properly when a client disconnects? The array value gets set to NULL rather than being dropped from the array.