# how to fix memory leak in setTimeout closure?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

Can someone please explain how to fix this memory leak in nodejs:

```
var foo = function (data, cb) {
    cb(data);
};

setInterval(function() {
    foo('asdf', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}, 500);
```

Comment: why do you think there is a memory leak here?

Comment: because the memory is increasing. Also I tried to comment the console.log(), the memory is increasing a lot slower but still increasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I agree with @vkurchatkin, there is no memory leak. I tried to run this code with small variations and my results: `node` processes had no memory incrementation. But my terminal emulator `rxvt` does. You should check yours.

Usefull topic: [How to prevent memory leaks in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733665/how-to-prevent-memory-leaks-in-node-js)

Comment: Agreed. Running the code in the question for several minutes showed no memory leak on mine...

Comment: I tested it on a linux server. `top` terminal, and there is no memory increasing. I was confused by windows terminal ).