# How to stop garbage collection on global object in Node for caching purposes?

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection

I'm caching an object in the global namespace so for example:
global.cachedObject = myObject;

but I notice that after a certain amount of time, node garbage collects it. Is there a way to tag the object in some way so that it doesn't get collected?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733665/how-to-prevent-memory-leaks-in-node-js

Comment: Bugs or very obscure edge cases nonwithstanding, only unreachable objects are GC'd. Is your object unreachable? If so, *your code* has a bug (if it's unreachable it can't be used for caching). If not, please provide more details. How do you determine that it's collected?

Comment: Well yeah, it's not used or referenced. Sometimes I just reference this object on an http GET request (to return it). I wanted to know how to force an object to stay.