# CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory ionic 3 Build prod Issue

Tags: angular, ionic3

Currently I am trying to build my ionic project to android apk file but I ran into CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory issue when in hit ionic cordova build android --prod --release. I googled and tried many fixes no luck

tries this not working

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\@ionic\app-scripts\bin\ionic-app-scripts.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node --max_old_space_size=4096  "%~dp0\..\@ionic\app-scripts\bin\ionic-app-scripts.js" %*
)
```

also tried all the ans mention in this question [Error in ionic cordova build android --prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897670/error-in-ionic-cordova-build-android-prod). But no luck Please help

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

First of all try npm install And follow the below steps

1. add this to the package.json scripts "ionic:build": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js build",
2. run the command: npm run ionic:build --prod
3. run the commands: cordova build android --release
4. cordova build ios --release