# IE\Firefox garbage collection for localhost\external site

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, memory-leaks

I've spent the last two days hunting JavaScript memory leaks in my web project and found out the thing that confused me.

My site is built using ASP.NET MVC and heavily use JavaScript together with jQuery library and bunch of plugins.

On my local machine I refresh the page and can see how memory is constantly increasing in IE8\Firefox 3.6. But, when I publish my site to the web the memory is cleared when I refresh the page.

It's a really confusing and I wonder whether any difference in IE\Firefox garbage collection when accessing sites from different zones (Intranet, internet) or from localhost\externla location?

Comment: Could you show some code so we could test this too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery definitely has some memory leaks...  If you use a ton of AJAX calls, here's one patch you might try to help yourself out:

[Simple jQuery Ajax call leaks memory in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429056/simple-jquery-ajax-call-leaks-memory-in-internet-explorer/2602690#2602690)

Other than that, you'll need to provide some code showing what kinds of things your page is doing...