# How to clean up JQuery JSONP request results?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jsonp

My javascript client makes a JSONP request via the JQuery $.ajax() method every second.
When I view the JavaScript console in Google chrome (13.0.782.215 m Windows) and click on the Resources button I can see that every second an item is added to the Scripts.
This item is the result of my JSONP request, it looks like this:

```
jQuery162007347695156931877_1314625724397({"Online": "True"})
```

These items just keep building up; the longer the page stays alive, the longer the list becomes. My question is how do I clean up these resources?

I have seen a lot of similar questions here, but most relate to some sort of memory leak relating to using JQuery for DOM manipulation. As far as I know I am not doing these things. Other questions relate to some vague memory leak issue which does not seem easy to trace down. (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752335/memory-leak-when-pulling-json-from-web)) I couldn't find a satisfying answer to this question as of yet, so I decided to post it.

I am not on some quest trying to trace down a vague memory leak, I just want to know why these JSONP request results are stacking up in Google Chrome, and of course, how to clean it all up.

I have a code snippet that will reproduce the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajaxSetup({
      // url: [edit:] I have removed the link since the question is answered now
      crossdomain: true,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      tiemout: 3000,
      success: myResult
  });

  function myRequest()
  {
    $.ajax();
  }

  function myResult(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
  {
    // do nothing
  }

  setInterval(myRequest, 1000);
});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Chrome is just displaying the activity on your page, i.e. it's displaying the history of what has happened on your page.

jQuery's implementation of JSONP probably creates a new script tag for each call.  If you want to write your own implementation of JSONP, you could reuse the same script tag, which might cause Chrome to only list this 'resource' once.  Either way, you're not going to have a resource problem in Chrome.