# javascript jsonp memory leak

Tags: javascript, ajax, memory-leaks, jsonp

I'm seeing the same problem described in [Memory Leak When Pulling JSON from WEB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752335/memory-leak-when-pulling-json-from-web).

I simply have a function that makes a jsonp ajax request periodically.  My function is called by another function triggered by a setInterval.

I see a memory leak in all broswers that I've tried, IE, Safari, FireFox.  Something I see in the Safari script debugger is that each response to an ajax request is listed as a script in the drop down list in the script debugger window, as if there is some kind of script object not getting cleaned up.

I'm using jquery 1.6.2.  It is a "long term" leak, not cleaned up after running for several minutes.

Any ideas what is causing this?

```
    request: function ()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: <myurl>
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "jsoncallback",
            timeout: 5000,
            cache: false,

            beforeSend: function (xhr)
            {
            },

            success: function (data, status, xhr)
            {
            },

            error: function (xhr, status, error)
            {
            },

            complete: function (req, status)
            {
            }
        });
    }
    ...
    setInterval(request, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact you're sending ajax request every 100 milliseconds is enough.

Be aware, setInterval(request, **100**); - 100 does not mean seconds, but milliseconds. 1 second = 1000 miliseconds

Comment: Thanks,yes I'm aware I'm sending requests at that rate.  The application requires it.  I'm in control of the server side and expect that kind of responsiveness.

Comment: @ThomasHamilton: can you tell me, for what?

Answer (score 0):

As far as a jQuery leaks, see [jQuery memory leak with DOM removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462649/jquery-memory-leak-with-dom-removal)

There is a utility for finding memory leaks: http://www.outofhanwell.com/ieleak/Drip-0.5.exe

@genesis is correct too.